# How to find an optimal shape with sections missing

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

Given an n by n matrix of integers, I want to find a part of the matrix that has the maximum sum with some restrictions.  In the version I can solve, I am allowed to draw two lines and remove everything below and/or to the right.  These can be one horizontal line and one diagonal line at 45 degrees (going up and right). For example with this 10 by 10 matrix:

```
  [[ 1, -3, -2,  2, -1, -3,  0, -2,  0,  0],
   [-1,  3,  3, -3,  0, -1,  0,  0, -2, -2],
   [-1,  0, -1,  0,  2,  1,  1, -3,  2,  1],
   [-3,  1, -3, -1,  1, -3, -2, -1, -3,  1],
   [ 1, -3,  1, -2,  2,  1, -3,  2, -3,  0],
   [-1, -2,  0, -2,  2, -3,  3, -1, -1,  2],
   [ 2,  2, -3, -1,  0, -1,  2,  0,  3,  0],
   [-1,  3, -1,  1, -1,  0,  0,  3, -3,  0],
   [ 3,  2,  1,  1,  2,  3,  0,  2,  0, -3],
   [ 0,  3,  2,  0, -1, -2,  3, -3, -3,  1]]
```

An optimal sum is 3 which you get by the shaded area here:

[image]

If `square` contains the 2d array then this code will find the location of the places where the bottom row should end to get the maximum sum:

```
max_sums = np.empty_like(square, dtype=np.int_)
max_sums[0] = np.cumsum(square[0])
for row_idx in range(1, dim):
    cusum = np.cumsum(square[row_idx])
    for col_idx in range(dim):
        if col_idx < dim - 1:
            max_sums[row_idx, col_idx] = cusum[col_idx] + max_sums[row_idx - 1, col_idx + 1]
        else:
            max_sums[row_idx, col_idx] = cusum[col_idx] + max_sums[row_idx - 1, col_idx]

maxes = np.argwhere(max_sums==max_sums.max())   # Finds all the locations of the max

print(f"The coordinates of the maximums are {maxes} with sum {np.max(max_sums)}")
```

## Problem

I would like to be able to leave out regions of the matrix defined by consecutive rows when finding the maximum sum. In the simpler version that I can solve I am only allowed to leave out rows at the bottom of the matrix. That is one region in the terminology we are using. The added restriction is that I am only allowed to leave out two regions at most.  For the example given above, let us say we leave out the first two rows and rows 3 to 5 (indexing from 0) and rerun the code above. We then get a sum of 26.

Excluded regions must exclude entire rows, not just parts of them.

[image]

I would like to do this for much larger matrices. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've seen a lot of these sorts of questions recently (which I've really enjoyed, I might add). I have to ask- would you happen to be assembling a library of sorts for solving these kinds of problems?

Comment: @DillonDavis Yes,  but really for my own interest.

Comment: If its not private, would you mind sharing a link?  I'd love to take a look around to learn.  If contributions are welcome, even better.

Comment: Anyways, how does the diagonal line play into the 2-region generalization? Can each have its own diagonal line? What if two regions of rows left out become connected by a diagonal line, are they counted as only one single region?

Comment: @DillonDavis Only one diagonal line. The diagonal line is just a rule about what to exclude so it can't add any elements from excluded rows. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DillonDavis  Sorry, I don't have anything online. It's just on my pc.

Comment: Right, but I mean w.r.t. connecting two excluded rows. E.g. exclude rows[0] and rows[2], and also include some arbitrary diagonal line such that at least one element on the RHS of rows[1] gets excluded.  The two excluded regions are now "connected" by this excluded portion of rows[1], for one contiguous region. I wanted to make sure don't also get to exclude say rows[4] since there's still <= 2 excluded regions, technically.

Comment: @DillonDavis I made an edit and added a comment. Does it help?

Comment: Your edit greatly clarifies things, thanks

Comment: Since you're doing this for a personal library, I showed how to solve a modest generalization of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that will handle any number of alternating include/exclude regions. (But always in that order.)

```
def optimize_exclude(matrix, blocks=5):
    """Finds the optimal exclusion pattern for a matrix.

    matrix is an nxm array of arrays.

    blocks is the number of include/exclude blocks. We
    start with an include block, so 5 blocks will include
    up to three stretches of rows and exclude the other 2.

    It returns (best_sum, diag, boundaries). So a return of
    (25, 15, [5, 7, 10, 12]) represents that we excluded
    all entries (i, j) where 5 <= i < 7, or 10 <= i < 12, or
    15 < i+j.

    It will run in time O(n*(n+m)*blocks).
    """
    sums = []
    # We start with a best which is excluding everything.
    best = (0, -1, [])
    n = len(matrix)
    if 0 == n:
        # Handle trivial edge case.
        return best
    m = len(matrix[0])
    for diag in range(n + m - 1):
        if diag < n:
            # Need to sum a new row.
            sums.append(0)

        # Add the diagonal of i+j = diag to sums.
        for i in range(max(0, diag-m+1), min(diag+1, n)):
            j = diag - i
            sums[i] += matrix[i][j]

        # Start dp. It will be an array of,
        # (total, (boundary, (boundary, ...()...))) with the
        # current block being the position. We include even
        # blocks, exclude odd ones.
        #
        # At first we can be on block 0, sum 0, no boundaries.
        dp = [(0, ())]
        if 1 < blocks:
            # If we can have a second block, we could start excluding.
            dp.append((0, (0, ())))

        for i, s in enumerate(sums):
            # Start next_dp with basic "sum everything."
            # We do this so that we can assume next_dp[block]
            # is always there in the loop.
            next_dp = [(dp[0][0] + s, dp[0][1])]
            for block, entry in enumerate(dp):
                total, boundaries = entry
                # Are we including or excluding this block?
                if 0 == block%2:
                    # Include row?
                    if next_dp[block][0] < total + s:
                        next_dp[block] = (total + s, boundaries)
                    # Start new block?
                    if block + 1 < blocks:
                        next_dp.append((total, (i, boundaries)))
                else:
                    # Exclude row?
                    if next_dp[block][0] < total:
                        next_dp[block] = entry
                    # Start new block?
                    if block + 1 < blocks:
                        next_dp.append((total + s, (i, boundaries)))
            dp = next_dp

        # Did we improve best?
        for total, boundaries in dp:
            if best[0] < total:
                best = (total, diag, boundaries)

    # Undo the linked list for convenience.
    total, diag, boundary_link = best
    reversed_boundaries = []
    while 0 < len(boundary_link):
        reversed_boundaries.append(boundary_link[0])
        boundary_link = boundary_link[1]
    return (total, diag, list(reversed(reversed_boundaries)))
```

And let's test it on your example.

```
matrix = [[ 1, -3, -2,  2, -1, -3,  0, -2,  0,  0],
          [-1,  3,  3, -3,  0, -1,  0,  0, -2, -2],
          [-1,  0, -1,  0,  2,  1,  1, -3,  2,  1],
          [-3,  1, -3, -1,  1, -3, -2, -1, -3,  1],
          [ 1, -3,  1, -2,  2,  1, -3,  2, -3,  0],
          [-1, -2,  0, -2,  2, -3,  3, -1, -1,  2],
          [ 2,  2, -3, -1,  0, -1,  2,  0,  3,  0],
          [-1,  3, -1,  1, -1,  0,  0,  3, -3,  0],
          [ 3,  2,  1,  1,  2,  3,  0,  2,  0, -3],
          [ 0,  3,  2,  0, -1, -2,  3, -3, -3,  1]]
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
print(optimize_exclude(matrix))
```

As we hope, it finds the solution `(26, 15, [0, 2, 3, 6])`. Which corresponds to a sum of 26, a diagonal of 15 (so exclude when `15 < i+j` - hits the end of the matrix by excluding from `matrix[9][7]` on), and excluding rows `0,1` then rows `3,4,5`. All of which exactly matches your diagram.

Comment: I tried this test case. [[ 1, -1], [ 1,  3]] which gives (4, 2, []).  I am not sure I understand where the diagonal is being drawn.  If we want 2 < i + j then that doesn't leave any of the matrix so I don't see how you get a sum of 4.

Comment: @Simd You put in a 2x2 matrix. So `i` and `j` are both `0` or `1`. Where `0` is the first row/column, and `1` is the second row/column. It is excluding everything where `2 < i+j` which is to say that the diagonal is being drawn off of the corner of the matrix, and you are excluding nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer. Do you think the factor of two running time overhead can be eliminated?  Your code looks at all diagonals which is where this factor comes from.  (Also, your answer deserves more upvotes.)

Comment: @Simd You can reduce it a bit in the second half by not redoing calculations on parts of `sums` that can't have changed. You can get a much bigger speedup with parallelization across diagonals with `numpy`. But you'd likely have to lose the ability to reconstruct what area was actually excluded.

Comment: I added a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861790/how-to-find-an-optimal-circular-area-with-regions-missing . Do you  think your approach would work there?

Comment: What does `sums` represent?

Comment: @Simd Here `sums` represents the sum in each row of values not excluded by the diagonal. That's why as the exclusion zone moves outwards, we add values to the `sums`.

Comment: What does it mean when you get one value in the list of boundaries? How should that be interpreted? Does [4] mean everything from row 4 onwards should be excluded?

Comment: @Simd A value on the boundary means that we're switching between including and excluding. We start including. So `[4, 6, 10, 15]` means include 0-3,exclude 4,5, include 6-9, exclude 10-14, and include 15 onwards.

Comment: I was trying to convert the code to numpy but it seems not to be so simple.